# Unix Shell Script Time Zone BST Or GMT

Tags: bash, shell, datetime, unix

This is what i'm trying to do:

I want to create a simple shell script that checks the current timezone in the UK.
i.e. BST or GMT.

I only can display the time for the current timezone the UK is in. i.e. UK is in GMT right now and I can only display that time. [TZ=GMT date]

Please note: I do not wish to permanently modify the UNIX time zone on the server (currently CET)

Based on that I need to do some calculations (which I'm fine with)
I have already searched and I cannot find anything specific to this problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you really want the timezone offset from UTC?

Comment: I simply want the shell script to echo out the BST & GMT. Regardless of what time zone we are in. This is because I want to do certain calculations based on whichever timezone we are in. Thanks

Comment: `date +%Z` will give you the current alphabetic time zone abbreviation.

Comment: Take a look at the [date(1) man page](http://linuxconfig.org/date-1-manual-page). You can output your own format; you might (for example) want something like this: `date +'%Z %F'`

Comment: Hi Lynn, Its not wuire what im looking for. I would like the shell action to simply tell me at present if we are BST or GMT and echo the time out accordingly. This enables me to perform calculations based on the timezone we are in.

Comment: Are you saying that `date +%Z` doesn't return that?

Comment: And `date +%:::z` returns a numeric that you can use for calculations... not sure what else you'd need.

Comment: I think @Sid may be missing that the clocks in the UK changed last weekend, so UK is on GMT now.

Answer (score 1):

To get the date for a particular timezone, you can do:

```
TZ=GMT date
```

(Or `date +%s` if you want epoch format, which is also TZ independent, but altogether friendlier for calculations. ).

For what it is *now*, relative time I think it's as simple as:

```
TZ=Europe/London date
```

Which I think should cause your system to report BST/GMT appropriately.

If you want it to specifically report the offset, you can use the `%z` format specifier:

```
TZ=Europe/London date +"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %z"
```

Comment: Yes - But this is not quite what I asked.. I already know how to get the present time (GMT)

Comment: OK. You can either use `%Z` or  `%z` depending if you want `GMT/BST` or `+0000/+0100`.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, It doesn't display the time in BST. I only get +0000 at the end, I think you are onto something though, As I can use this in other calculations however at this stage I just want the shell script to tell me whether we are in BST or GMT

Comment: Well, yeah. It will. Because the UK is on GMT right now. Clocks changed last weekend....